# My Navigation got corrupted after hiding and showing some subsite links

Tags: development, master-page, navigation, publishing-site, 2016

I am working on a sharepoint server 2016. and i have created a new site collection of type team site and i enable the publishing infrastructure features. and inside the navigation i define to show the subsites links as follow:-

[image]

now i have 6 subsites and everything was working well, until i do the following:-

1. i edit the navigation links from the Quick Launch links.
2. i specify to hide some links as follow:-
   [image]

Now after that i got a lot of duplicate items showing as shown in the first picture... ...so not sure if there is a way to reset my navigation links to only show 6 links represents my sub-sites without any duplicates ?